# Tab completion for git branches showing old/outdated entries

Tags: git, autocomplete

I'm on a sort of frankendebian stretch/sid (not the best idea, I know; planning on reinstalling soon).

Tab completion works for git branch names in git repo directories:

```
:~/project $ git checkout <TAB><TAB>
Display all 200 possibilities? (y or n)

:~/project $ git checkout private-rl_<TAB><TAB>
private-rl_1219_misspelled_locale_zhtw   private-rl_1950_scheduler_offset         private-rl_bootstrap_rake_tasks
private-rl_1854_ldap_filter_reset        private-rl_bootstrap_rake_task
```

But some of the branches it shows don't exist anymore:

```
:~/project $ git branch
* develop
  private-rl_1219_misspelled_locale_zhtw
  stable
```

This also happens for deleted **remote** branches.

What's going on here? Does the git completion script keep a cache of old branches that can be flushed somehow? How can I stop these branches from accumulating in my tab-completion results?

Comment: Are you sure they are not tags? Autocompletion takes into account tags, and many other things. See top comments on https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

Comment: I'm 100% sure they're not tags. I created and deleted those branches myself. Weird though — I just did `$ sudo fd --hidden --no-ignore git-completion /`, and didn't get any results.

Comment: Do `git branch -a` to see all branches. Remote branches may be taken into account also.

Comment: Thanks, it was references to deleted remotes (see answer below).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks to some gentle prodding from @PatrickMevzek:

The branches I was seeing were actually [references to remote branches that had already been deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072171/how-do-you-remove-an-invalid-remote-branch-reference-from-git). To quote the top answer from the SO thread linked above,

```
$ git remote prune origin
```

fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup, there is another source of what might look like old or deleted branches - your git-completion may also be suggesting *tags* along with branches.

I was fooled by this recently - our CI/CD pipeline tags all our builds, and even though certain branches would be released and/or deleted years ago, the tags persisted. Cleaning up old tags on the remote was the solution here ([there is a guide here](https://devconnected.com/how-to-delete-local-and-remote-tags-on-git/).

Answer (score -1):

git(1) comes with contributed files in `git/contrib/completion/` in the source. The script for your shell handles completions.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment, but the script as linked by @PatrickMevzek above is already over 3,000 lines long. If I had all day to read through `git-completion.bash`, well, I'd probably take my dogs for a hike instead anyway.